# Convert Varchar Column to Datetime format - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table of data imported from CSV as follows:

```
FirstTimeTaken      LatestTimeTaken     Market                  Outcome         Odds    NumberOfBets    VolumeMatched   InPlay
03/08/2013 15:30:14 03/08/2013 15:32:28 Over/Under 3.5 Goals    Over 3.5 Goals  5       10              118             1
03/08/2013 14:26:40 03/08/2013 14:29:43 Correct Score           0 - 0           7       12              279             1
03/08/2013 15:15:34 03/08/2013 15:27:39 Match Odds              Barnsley        110     7               9               1
28/07/2013 16:57:26 29/07/2013 21:35:55 Match Odds              Barnsley        3       9               35              0
```

I had to import the first 2 columns in varchar format because I was getting errors trying to import as datetime. Now I have the data in a table, I need to convert the Column format from Varchar to Datetime. I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE #CSVTest_Data
ALTER COLUMN FirstTimeTaken DATETIME
ALTER TABLE #CSVTest_Data
ALTER COLUMN LatestTimeTaken DATETIME
```

This results in error: 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'.
I know that removing the last row of data gets rid of the problem, so I suspect that the system thinks the date format is MM/DD/YYYY whereas it is actually DD/MM/YYYY.
The following query works fine:

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(50),FirstTimeTaken,105) from #CSVTest_Data 
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(50),LatestTimeTaken,105) from #CSVTest_Data
```

But this does not convert the column format to datetime. I would appreciate some help on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What method are you using to import these?

Comment: A simple `Cast(FirstTimeTaken as datetime)` should do the trick, if all the fields are formatted like the ones we see.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: I'm thinking this doesn't work:  `SELECT CAST('28/07/2013 16:57:26' AS DATETIME)`.  At least not in the OP's environment.

Comment: @DMason Jonas's answer makes much more sense to me now.  Not sure what happened to my reading comprehension skills....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `SET DATEFORMAT`.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Comment: I added your line of code in before my ALTER COLUMN commands and it worked perfectly. I even commented out your line of code after the first run and everything still works fine. Has that code permanently modified my settings?

Comment: Yes, you might want to run `SET DATEFORMAT mdy` once you are done to reset.

Comment: I am in UK so I expect it should be set as DMY permanently. Thanks

Comment: I discovered that after logging off and back on, the DATEFORMAT was lost and needed to be reset. The trick to fix this permanently is to select Security-->Logins in Object Explorer. Then locate the user and right click properties. At the bottom you will see Default Language. Changing this to British English gives me a permanent fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the data from your #Temp table as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, FirstTimeTaken, 103 ),
    CONVERT(DATETIME, LatestTimeTaken, 103)
FROM #CSVTest_Data
```

This returns the fields as DATETIME data types.  From there, do whatever you need to.