# Convert a string of date in dd/mm/yyyy format to a date column in SQL Server

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have an excel sheet which contains date in format dd/mm/yyyy. Now when I import it in SQL Server 2008, it takes it as varchar() column. How would I be able to update or convert that varchar() to datetime.

Note: `Convert()`, `Datepart()` & `Alter Column` are not working. Any idea on
 how would I be able to extract date, month & year from that string?

Any suggestions are welcome.

[Download SpreadSheet From Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frjgs6vmadow93b/DataFile.xls?dl=0)

You will notice that some dates are aligned differently than others. Dates which are left aligned gets imported as varchar() while dates which are right aligned come as null.

Please could someone try to import it and check if its true or not.

> Note - I am using KingSoft's Spreadsheet not MS Excel.

Comment: Any idea? Ok guessing, **one** Excel sheet might be a different from  automatic pipeline, but Excel has the concept of types / format on the  cells, so it might be best fit to adapt that on Excel level. Are you using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizzard, or export to CSV, or ... (maybe that is clear to others already, but not for me). What you tried reads like on SQL level, as if Excel Transformation not possible, then maybe try `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` or similar as eg. suggested in [Convert Varchar Column to Datetime format - SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22512678/378826)?

Comment: Format the cells as `yyyymmdd` and they should import into SQL 2008 without a problem.

Comment: @Dilettant Thanx a lott for your suggestion.

Comment: @Jeeped I tried it but i dont understand why excel is not converting it.

Comment: Maybe click on such a cell in excel and open the format cell dialog, watch the value displayed also in the "entry field" that should be doable on excel level ... then it will work as @Jeeped suggested (I do not have access to such a DB.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi - It has been my experience that importing to SQL 2008 R2 (and just about any other version) can be tricky with varchar's but if dates are brought in as `yyyymmdd` (with no errors or blanks in the column) then DMY vs MDY and `,` vs `;` vs `<tab>` can be disregarded no matter what the server's regional settings are. fwiw, I have more than a small bit of experience in this.

Comment: Assuming @Jeeped suggestion fails you, which it shouldn't, what error are you getting when you try: `select cast([varCharColumn] as date)`

Comment: I have attached the excel sheet in my question edit. Please try to reproduce the issue I am getting.

Comment: How exactly do you "import" that Excel file? Which tool do you use?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I use "Sql Server 2008's Task->Import Data" Tool to import the spreadsheet into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply custom format for your Date Column in excel before importing it to the Database. Change your date column has Datetime in Database. Once you apply this custom formatting then you can directly import the data to DB Table.

See the sample screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Could you try this method on my sheet.